# form with input type=text not working when render inside a jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a popup form from this url: http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/asp-net-mvc-ajax-dialog-form-using-jquery-ui/. It loads a jquery dialog inside a div by using the load function.

I have a form with several text fields and 1 upload file field. This form works correctly, and I've successfully post this form to an action and recover the HttpPostedFile object.

But when I load the same form in a jquery dialog using the load function and post the same form to the same action that previously worked, it failed. I'm not sure why but the HttpPostedFile object is always null.

Actual codes:
Using the DialogForm.js specified above I called the helper function:

```
@Html.DialogFormButton("Add", Url.Action("Add", "X", new { id = y }), "", "targetId", Url.Action("List", "X", new { id = y }))
```

This code should load the view in a modal popup:

```
$('.dialogLink').live('click', function () {
        var element = $(this);
...
$(dialogDiv).load(this.href, function () {
            $(this).dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                title: dialogTitle,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        // Manually submit the form
                        var form = $('form', this);
                        $(form).submit();
                    },
...
```

Actually I call a view and the view loads an editor template.

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test", "X", new { }, new AjaxOptions { }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model, "editorView")
        }
```

The editor view contains several textboxes and the input type file element:

```
 <tr>
        <td class="label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PathToAttachment)
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="field_container">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileUpload, new { type = "file" })
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

All the elements are member of a model class. Which is the parameter of the Post Add method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAttachment(AttachmentModel model) { 
  if (model.FileUpload.ContentLength > 0) { }
}
```

The problem: model.FileUpload is always null, but the remaining of the form elements has value. Note that it only happens when I used the DialogForm.js in loading the form. Otherwise when I load the form in a simple page (not popup) I can successfully get the FileUpload value.

Resolved, I found out that it's not possible to submit an ajax form with file, so I got no choice but to use this library:

http://code.google.com/p/ajax-file-upload-struts2/source/browse/trunk/src/main/resources/template/com/davidjc/javascript/ajaxfileupload.js?r=4

It creates an invisible iframe with form elements and post to the server automatically.

Thanks

czetsuya

Comment: Include the relevant parts of your code - the jQuery/Javascript as well as the HTML.

Comment: Seriously, please add code or an example where it is not working, no one can help you when your question is as vague as it is :)

Comment: Sorry about that, code added.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `<form>` tag in your modal window has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set correctly.

Comment: Yes I already have that tag. Actually the form works when not loaded in a jquery dialog. So I'm guessing it has something to do with javascript/ajax.